# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array from array with db items

Tags: php

I am trying to read through an array in the same way I do many other times on my site. This one is giving me the Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.
In my class I have:

```
public $productlist = array();
//GetFeatured 
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
$this->productlist[] = $obj;
}
```

In my page I am trying to display it:

```
$prod = new product;
$prod->GetFeatured();
for($ind = 0; $ind <= count($prod->productlist) - 1; $ind++){
echo $prod->productlist[$ind]['productid'];
}
```

This populates the array but I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `->name` instead of `['name']`: `echo $prod->productlist[$ind]->productid;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching as object here:

```
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
```

then trying to access as array here:

```
echo $prod->productlist[$ind]['productid'];
```

Try it like this:

```
echo $prod->productlist[$ind]->productid;
```

---

Another way is using `fetch_assoc` at the place of `fetch_object`

```
while($obj = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

then this stays like this:

```
echo $prod->productlist[$ind]['productid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get data from object in array style your class needs to implement the [ArrayAccess interface](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/class.arrayaccess.php)